# How to get the physical address in macosx kernel for a virtual address for a particular process?

Tags: macos, kernel, virtual-memory, kernel-extension

I was wondering if there is an existing system call/API for accessing getting the physical address of the virtual address?
If there is none then some direction on how to get that working ?

Also, how to get the physical address of MMIO which is non-pageable physical memory ?

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in `IOMemoryDescriptor` and `IODMACommand` objects.

If the memory in question is kernel-allocated, it should be allocated by creating an `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor` in the first place. If that's not possible, or if it's a buffer allocated in user space, you can wrap the relevant pointer using `IOMemoryDescriptor::withAddressRange(address, length, options, task)` or one of the other factory functions. In the case of `withAddressRange`, the `address` passed in must be virtual, in the address space of `task`.

You can directly grab physical address ranges from an `IOMemoryDescriptor` by calling the `getPhysicalSegment()` function (only valid between `prepare()`…`complete()` calls). However, normally you would do this for creating scatter-gather lists (DMA), and for this purpose Apple strongly recommends the `IODMACommand`. You can create these using `IODMACommand::withSpecification()`. Then use the `genIOVMSegments()` function to generate the scatter-gather list.

Modern Macs, and also some old PPC G5s contain an IOMMU (Intel calls this VT-d), so the system memory addresses you pass to PCI/Thunderbolt devices are not in fact physical, but IO-Mapped. `IODMACommand` will do this for you, as long as you use the "system mapper" (the default) and set `mappingOptions` to `kMapped`. If you're preparing addresses for the *CPU*, not a device, you will want to turn off mapping - use `kIOMemoryMapperNone` in your `IOMemoryDescriptor` options. Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you probably don't need `IODMACommand` in this case either.

Note: it's often wise to pool and reuse your IODMACommand objects, rather than freeing and reallocating them.

Regarding MMIO, I assume you mean PCI BARs and similar - for `IOPCIDevice`, you can grab an `IOMemoryDescriptor` representing the memory-mapped device range using `getDeviceMemoryWithRegister()` and similar functions.

**Example:**

If all you want are pure CPU-space physical addresses for a given virtual memory range in some task, you can do something like this (untested as a complete kext that uses it would be rather large):

```
// INPUTS:
mach_vm_address_t virtual_range_start = …; // start address of virtual memory
mach_vm_size_t virtual_range_size_bytes = …; // number of bytes in range
task_t task = …; // Task object of process in which the virtual memory address is mapped
IOOptionBits direction = kIODirectionInOut; // whether the memory will be written or read, or both during the operation
IOOptionBits options =
    kIOMemoryMapperNone  // we want raw physical addresses, not IO-mapped
    | direction;

// Process for getting physical addresses:

IOMemoryDescriptor* md = IOMemoryDescriptor::withAddressRange(
    virtual_range_start, virtual_range_size_bytes, direction, task);
// TODO: check for md == nullptr

// Wire down virtual range to specific physical pages
IOReturn result = md->prepare(direction);
// TODO: do error handling

IOByteCount offset = 0;
while (offset < virtual_range_size_bytes)
{
    IOByteCount segment_len = 0;
    addr64_t phys_addr = md->getPhysicalSegment(offset, &len, kIOMemoryMapperNone);
    // TODO: do something with physical range of segment_len bytes at address phys_addr here

    offset += segment_len;
}

/* Unwire. Call this only once you're done with the physical ranges
 * as the pager can change the physical-virtual mapping outside of
 * prepare…complete blocks. */
md->complete(direction);
md->release();
```

As explained above, this is not suitable for generating DMA scatter-gather lists for device I/O. Note also this code is only valid for 64-bit kernels. You'll need to be careful if you still need to support ancient 32-bit kernels (OS X 10.7 and earlier) because virtual and physical addresses can still be 64-bit (64-bit user processes and PAE, respectively), but not all memory descriptor functions are set up for that. There are 64-bit-safe variants available to be used for 32-bit kexts.

Comment: I got most of what you said, i want one to one mapping of virtual address to physical address, can you tell me what function can help me achieve that ? So, far looking into IOMemoryDescriptor, pmap, vm_map, I have not been able to find a straight forward function that does the translation

Comment: @Anurag You can do it with the IOMemoryDescriptor. I will add an example when I'm back in the office.

Comment: @Anurag I've added an example for getting pure CPU-physical addresses for a virtual range. For (PCI) DMA you will need to use the `IODMACommand` API instead, but you haven't quite clarified which you wanted, so I had to guess.

Comment: @SteffX DriverKit has similar APIs, I think starting with macOS 11.

Comment: @pmdj — Thank you. After verification, it is available from macOS 10.15 so it won't help me at the moment. But I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Physical addresses aren‘t otherwise exposed to user space, not that they‘d be especially helpful. What problem are you specifically trying to solve?